# Debugging c++ code behind python

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, gdb

I am trying to debug C++ code behind python for this library ([faster rcnn](https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn)).

I followed the instruction [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb).

Say I like to stop a break point at solver.cpp and line 188.

```
gdb -ex r --args python ./tools/train_faster_rcnn_alt_opt.py --gpu 0 --net_name headhand --weights data/imagenet_models/VGG_CNN_M_1024.v2.caffemodel --imdb headhand_train --cfg experiments/cfgs/config.yml
```

I press `Ctrl + c`

then

```
gdb python 8504

break solver.cpp:188
```

then `type c and enter`

But never break at solver.cpp. How can I debug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not debugging the python interpreter itself, you don't need any python debugging stuff described in the linked article. You can use the regular interpreter and no extensions. You also don't want to run gdb twice. You only need to make sure you set your breakpoint early enough.

```
$ gdb python --args <your-args> # no -x r 
(gdb) break <your-breakpoint>
No symbol table is loaded. Use the "file" comand.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n])
```

Answer "y".

```
(gdb) run
```

That's it.

Comment: I did as what you mentioned and I have (gdb) run                                                                     
Starting program:  --gpu 0 --net_name headhand --weights data/imagenet_models/VGG_CNN_M_1024.v2.caffemodel --imdb headhand_train --cfg experiments/cfgs/config.yml
No executable file specified.
Use the "file" or "exec-file" command.

Answer (score 0):

You probably has passed your breakpoint (before GDB got started). You should, per the [instructions](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb) mentioned:

> run python under gdb from the start

Try to `run` your `python` under GDB.

Read about [Debugging with GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/).

You might want to use a `python` interpreter built with [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) debug info, so compiled with `-g` (and of course your `solver.cpp` should also be compiled with `-g`). Since Python is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) recompiling it with `-g` should be pretty simple.

BTW, are you sure of the line position 188 of your breakpoint? Did you try to add more breakpoints in `solver.cpp` at other positions, or to break at function names?